# XNA blurred sprites when scaled

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I have a 32x32 sprite for a pixel art based game but when I scale the sprite up, it becomes very blurred, I have read about online and I believe the solution lies somewhere in `SamplerState`.

I've had a look on the MSDN and around StackOverflow and Gamedev but found nothing useful to a beginner like me. A few code sample but I have no idea where I could work them into my project.

I'm not providing any of my code yet since I'm sure it isn't of any use. All I want is someone to explain how or even just throw some simpler code at me. I don't mind which, most likely I would like to have it explained becuase then I would know how to do it in the future.

Comment: Are you using the `SpriteBatch`? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215027/nearest-neighbor-zoom) might be of interest.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what was happening, also I wasn't sure what to put for all the other parameters but `spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.None, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise);` (pasted from linked question) worked perfectly!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`SpriteBatch.Begin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/xna/bb195109(v=xnagamestudio.42)) can take a SamplerState parameter. All you do is pass in `SamplerState.PointClamp`

```
SpriteBatch.Begin (SpriteSortMode, BlendState, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState, RasterizerState)
```

Just like that but replace SpriteSortMode, BlendState, DepthStencilState, and RasterizerState with your desired values. Some can take null if you do not wish to use it.

Comment: So How would I do that? I forgot to mention that I'm a beginner :P

Comment: At `spriteBatch.Begin();` in your `Draw` method, just change that.
Do not copy this code thought, just follow the arguments.